# I am building a GUI for my app but get errors. Why?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI to my app using tkinter but it doesn't work. why? The program needs to take 2 inputs from user and save them in variables also I marked where I got errors in the code below

```
import tkinter as tk

# making the window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("AutoWhatsUp")
root.geometry('500x500')

# getting phone number from user
enter_number = tk.Label(root, text = "enter below the phone number you want to message")
enter_number.pack()
filed = tk.Entry(root)
filed.pack()
def get_number():
    phone_num = filed.get()
    done_procces_phone = tk.Label(root, text = 'Phone number procced!').pack() # getting error here
confirm_number = tk.Button(root, text = 'procces number', command = get_number).pack() #getting error here
# getting the message
enter_mess = tk.Label(root, text = 'enter below the message').pack() #getting error here
enter_mess_here = tk.Entry(root).pack() #getting error here
def getting_message():
    message_here = enter_mess_here.get()
    print(message_here)
    done_procces_mess = tk.Label(root, text = "done!").pack() #getting error here
get_mess = tk.Button(root, text = "procces message", command = getting_message).pack() #getting error here


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you also provide the error message?

Comment: Correct your entry first create `enter_mess_here = tk.Entry(root)` then pack it `enter_mess_here.pack()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you put None in your variable `enter_mess_here` here:

```
enter_mess_here = tk.Entry(root).pack() #getting error here
```

and in your function when you want to get the value it's not getting value from `Entry` it's getting from Nothing. So it raises an error.

First assign your `Entry` to a variable then use `pack`, so this will work:

```
enter_mess_here = tk.Entry(root)
enter_mess_here.pack()
```